# android crop image from gallery nullpointexception

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap, android-crop

I'm working in Camera.i want to choose image from my gallery  and crop selected photo and then show it in my  imageview.i wrote some code  but i have problem in cropping.
this is a my error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference




  private void CropPictureFromGallery()
{



    Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
    startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

}




  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            mAvatar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is a my code
I have problem in Cropping image because when i removed crop my app working perfect
what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: first of all check what're you getting in `targetUri` by debugiing this `Uri targetUri = data.getData();` if it's getting null you're not getting the cropped Image Uri.

and then do this `Bitmap Decoding` operation in `AsyncTask` coz it's a costly process.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select Action_Pick intent

   ```
                           Intent intent;
                           intent = new Intent(
                                   Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                           intent.setType("image/*");
                           Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                   "Choose a Picture");
                           startActivityForResult(chooser,
                                   RequestCode.REQ_GALLERY);
   ```
2. OnActivityResult get the image from URI

   ```
          case RequestCode.REQ_GALLERY:
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               Uri PhotoURI = data.getData();
               Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
               try {
                   bitmapImage = decodeBitmap(PhotoURI);
                   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getCurrActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(PhotoURI));

                   doCrop(getImageUri(getCurrActivity(), bitmapImage));
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           break;

   public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
   String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
   return Uri.parse(path);
    }
   ```
3. Apply crop operation

   ```
   private void doCrop(Uri mCurrentPhotoPath) {
   Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
   cropIntent.setDataAndType(mCurrentPhotoPath, "image/*");
   cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
   cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
   cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
   cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 320);
   cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 320);

   File cameraFolder;

   cameraFolder = new File(AppConstants.BASE_FOLDER);

   if (!cameraFolder.exists()) {
       cameraFolder.mkdirs();
   }

   mSourceFileName = "/IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

   File photo = new File(cameraFolder, mSourceFileName);
   try {
       photo.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   Uri mCropImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

   cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCropImageUri);

   startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RequestCode.REQ_CROP_IMG);
    }
   ```

Comment: this is a perfect example ,but can you tell me what is a wrong in my code?