# How to crop Gallery images in Marshmallow 6.0 and above versions

Tags: android

I am not able to crop the image from gallery in Marshmallow 6.0 and above versions, but Camera images are cropped.

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/uCrop

Comment: try this [image cropper lib](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734107/android-crop-image-from-gallery-nullpointexception